# Pandas DataFrame with MultiIindex and .combine_first does not work as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm trying to add some measurement data to a bigger Pandas DataFrame. The DataFrame contains some columns with the measured data (e.g. start-up time, memory usage, ...). Its index is a MultiIndex (part-number and sw-version).

After each measurement several new rows are collected. These new rows I wanted to add to the existing DataFrame. To avoid duplicates I use the DataFrame method combined_first().

However if I add the same measured data several times, I actually expect no further changes of the DataFrame. However the DataFrame grows because the measured data is added several times.

Code example:

```py
import pandas as pd
a1 = pd.DataFrame({'Part-Number':['A1A', 'A1A', 'A1A'],
                   'SW-Version':['1.0','1.0', '1.0'],
                   'C':[33, 2, 3],
                   'D':[44, 2, 3],
                   'E':[55, 2, 3]})

a2 = pd.DataFrame({'Part-Number':['A1A', 'A1A', 'A1A'],
                   'SW-Version':['1.2', '1.2', '1.2'],
                   'C':[55, 55, 55],
                   'D':[55, 55, 55],
                   'E':[55, 55, 55]})

a1.set_index(['Part-Number', 'SW-Version'], inplace=True)
a2.set_index(['Part-Number', 'SW-Version'], inplace=True)
```

First call:

```py
data = a1.combine_first(a2)
print(data)

                           C     D     E
Part-Number SW-Version                  
A1A         1.0         33.0  44.0  55.0
            1.0          2.0   2.0   2.0
            1.0          3.0   3.0   3.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
```

Second call of .combine_first():

```py
data = data.combine_first(a2)
print(data)

                           C     D     E
Part-Number SW-Version                  
A1A         1.0         33.0  44.0  55.0
            1.0          2.0   2.0   2.0
            1.0          3.0   3.0   3.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
```

I actually expected that the DataFrame is not changed by second call?!
My "expected" output after any further call of combine_first():

```py
data = data.combine_first(a2)
print(data)

                           C     D     E
Part-Number SW-Version                  
A1A         1.0         33.0  44.0  55.0
            1.0          2.0   2.0   2.0
            1.0          3.0   3.0   3.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
            1.2         55.0  55.0  55.0
```

Any idea why this happens?
Why does the second add the same rows three times?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have dupplicate in the index which is make it hard for combina_first yield the correct result

Comment: Since it is okay to have duplicates, how can we know that rows were already added to your dataframe?

Comment: I think if you have duplicates in your indesx, combine_first appends data rather than overwriting, as it doesn't know what to do with duplicate indexes.

Comment: Hmm, according to the documentation, I actually expected that the new data (columns) are only considered if the existing data has empty (NAN) cells. Therefore the duplicate index should not matter in this case.
Because there are no empty cells...

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Understanding better the OP situation, here is a solution that detects duplicates and handles them properly.

```
def add_data(data, df):
    try:
        data = data.append(df, verify_integrity=True)
    except ValueError:
        print('detected duplicates; dropping only the duplicate rows')
        idx_names = data.index.names
        data = data.reset_index().append(df.reset_index()).drop_duplicates()
        data = data.set_index(idx_names)
    return data
```

Example (with the data from the question):

```
# init
data = a1.copy()

# addition
data = add_data(data, a1)
print(data)

# output:
detected duplicates; dropping only the duplicate rows
                         C   D   E
Part-Number SW-Version            
A1A         1.0         55  55  55
            1.0         33  44  55
            1.0          2   2   2
            1.0          3   3   3

data = add_data(data, a2)
print(data)

# output:
detected duplicates; dropping only the duplicate rows
                         C   D   E
Part-Number SW-Version            
A1A         1.0         55  55  55
            1.0         33  44  55
            1.0          2   2   2
            1.0          3   3   3
            1.2         55  55  55
```

**No-index solution:**

Perhaps you should keep your data without index during collection (SQL-style). When later you want to do some analysis on the collected data or some display, you will surely try some groupby and aggregate.

So, for example:

```
# do not build an index, just collect the data; comment out these two lines:
# a1.set_index(['Part-Number', 'SW-Version'], inplace=True)
# a2.set_index(['Part-Number', 'SW-Version'], inplace=True)

# add new data:
data = a1.append(a2).drop_duplicates()
print(data)

  Part-Number SW-Version   C   D   E
0         A1A        1.0  55  55  55
1         A1A        1.0  33  44  55
2         A1A        1.0   2   2   2
3         A1A        1.0   3   3   3
0         A1A        1.2  55  55  55


# add duplicate data on purpose:
data = data.append(a2).drop_duplicates()
print(data)

  Part-Number SW-Version   C   D   E
0         A1A        1.0  55  55  55
1         A1A        1.0  33  44  55
2         A1A        1.0   2   2   2
3         A1A        1.0   3   3   3
0         A1A        1.2  55  55  55
```

Later, you may want to summarize your data, and in the process add the multi-index, for example:

```
data.groupby(['Part-Number', 'SW-Version']).agg(
    ['min', 'mean', 'median', 'max', 'size']
)

                         C                          D                       \
                       min   mean median max size min mean median max size   
Part-Number SW-Version                                                       
A1A         1.0          2  23.25     18  55    4   2   26   23.5  55    4   
            1.2         55  55.00     55  55    1  55   55   55.0  55    1   

                         E                         
                       min   mean median max size  
Part-Number SW-Version                             
A1A         1.0          2  28.75     29  55    4  
            1.2         55  55.00     55  55    1
```

Note: I find it a bit bizarre that you want to reject measurements that happen to match numerically previous ones. This would affect stats you may derive from the measurements. Now, if instead you are really at risk of counting multiple times the same measurements, then make sure you disambiguate them, for example with a `uuid.uuid4()` and/or a timestamp. When I measure systems, I actually always have both.

Comment: You are right, it must look weird for you. Actually my intentions is not to suppress valid measurement results. I actually want to avoid that the users add the same log file several times to the data store. 
For the sake of simplicity I haven't mentioned that the multi index also contains additional information like a timestamp.

Comment: Meanwhile I guess I'll follow your proposal and remove the duplicates afterwards. Although I feel a little bit uncomfortable with that solution. Searching and removing duplicates within the whole data store might be expensive if the date store grows. That's the reason why I wanted to avoid duplicates before adding...

Comment: I see. Well, `combine_first()`'s behavior is under-described in the case of duplicate index on either side; one could argue one way or another, but the truth is that it's undefined. Understanding better your case, you may then want to indeed have a multiindex as in your original question, and use [`df.append(..., verify_integrity=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to guarantee unicity of the index. Use a `except ValueError` to catch the case of attempted insertion of duplicates, and handle that case there.

Comment: I just updated my answer accordingly. So now you have options...